# SearchContainer unknown property while sorting columns

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I have a `view.jsp` of a portlet `sampleimportlog_WAR_Testportlet` where I display the entities `SampleImportLog`in a `searchContainer`from the database query. I get the results

[image]

This is the `searchContainer` in `view.jsp`

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="sampleImportLog-empty-results-message"  orderByType="<%= orderByType %>">
        <%

        List<SampleImportLog> allSampleImportLogs = SampleImportLogLocalServiceUtil.getSampleImportLogs(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
        List<SampleImportLog> sampleImportLogsPerPage = ListUtil.subList(allSampleImportLogs, searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd());
        List<SampleImportLog> sortableSampleImportLogs = new ArrayList<SampleImportLog>(sampleImportLogsPerPage);
        if(Validator.isNotNull(orderByCol)){
            //Pass the column name to BeanComparator to get comparator object
            BeanComparator comparator = new BeanComparator(orderByCol);
            if(orderByType.equalsIgnoreCase("asc")){
                //It will sort in ascending order
                Collections.sort(sortableSampleImportLogs, comparator);
            }else{
                //It will sort in descending order
                //Collections.reverse(sortableSampleImportLogs);
                Collections.sort(sortableSampleImportLogs, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
            }

        }
        searchContainer.setResults(sortableSampleImportLogs);
        searchContainer.setTotal(SampleImportLogLocalServiceUtil.getSampleImportLogsCount());

        %>

            <liferay-ui:search-container-row
                className="com.test.portlet.xxx.model.SampleImportLog"
                keyProperty="importId"
                modelVar="sampleImportLog" escapedModel="<%= true %>"
            >


                <portlet:renderURL var="viewSampleImportDetailsURL">
                    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/sample/sampleimportlog/view_details.jsp" />
                    <portlet:param name="uuid" value="<%= sampleImportLog.getUuid() %>" />
                </portlet:renderURL>

                <portlet:actionURL name="deleteSampleImport" var="deleteSampleImportURL">
                    <portlet:param name="importId" value="<%= String.valueOf(sampleImportLog.getImportId()) %>" />
                    <portlet:param name="uuid" value="<%= String.valueOf(sampleImportLog.getUuid()) %>" />
                </portlet:actionURL>

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    name="uuid"
                    property="uuid" 
                    orderable="true"
                    orderableProperty="uuid"
                    href="<%= viewSampleImportDetailsURL %>"
                />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    name="File Name"
                    property="fileName"
                    orderable="true"
                    orderableProperty="fileName"
                    href="<%= viewSampleImportDetailsURL %>"
                />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    name="Imported By"
                    property="fullNameImporter"
                    orderable="true"
                    orderableProperty="fullNameImporter"
                    href="<%= viewSampleImportDetailsURL %>"
                />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    name="Date Of Import"
                    property="dateOfImport"
                    orderable="true"
                    orderableProperty="dateOfImport"
                    href="<%= viewSampleImportDetailsURL %>"
                />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
                    <liferay-ui:icon-delete url="<%= deleteSampleImportURL.toString() %>" 
                        message="<%= \"Delete this import\" %>" 
                        confirmation="<%= \"Are you sure you want to delete this import? \" +
                                \"This will delete the import log as well as all the samples imported in this batch from the file \" 
                                + sampleImportLog.getFileName()+\".\" %>"
                    />
                </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>
            </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

        <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
    </liferay-ui:search-container>
```

When I click on the rows, I get the `uuid (from the first column)`. With this `uuid`, I query the another entity named `Sample` and show the details in another page say `view_details.jsp`. I can list the `sample entities` similarly in searchContainer in the `view_details.jsp`. Until here everything is working fine.

The `searchContainer` in `view_details.jsp` looks like this

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="sample-empty-results-message"  orderByType="<%= orderByType %>" >

<%

    List<Sample> samplesByuuid = SampleLocalServiceUtil.getSamplesByuuid(uuid);
    List<Sample> samplesByuuidPerPage = ListUtil.subList(samplesByuuid, searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd());
    List<Sample> sortableSamplesByuuid = new ArrayList<Sample>(samplesByuuidPerPage);
    if(Validator.isNotNull(orderByCol)){
        //Pass the column name to BeanComparator to get comparator object
        BeanComparator comparator = new BeanComparator(orderByCol);
        if(orderByType.equalsIgnoreCase("asc")){
            //It will sort in ascending order
            Collections.sort(sortableSamplesByuuid, comparator);
        }else{
            //It will sort in descending order
            Collections.sort(sortableSamplesByuuid, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
        }

    }
    searchContainer.setResults(sortableSamplesByuuid);
    searchContainer.setTotal(samplesByuuid.size());
%>
<liferay-ui:search-container-row
            className="com.test.portlet.xxx.model.Sample"
            keyProperty="sampleDbId"
            modelVar="sample" escapedModel="<%= true %>"
        >

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="uuid_"
                property="uuid_"
                orderable="true"
                orderableProperty="uuid_"

            />

<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                name="container"
                property="container" 
                orderable="true"
                orderableProperty="container"
            />
...
...
</liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Now when I click one of the headers to sort the results in searchContainer in `view_details.jsp`, which is coming from a different entity, I get the error **`Unknown property 'xxx' on class com.test.portlet.model.impl.SampleImportLogImpl'`**.

What I understand is, the portlet is tied to an entity `SampleImportLog`. I am tyring to sort the results in the `view_details.jsp` by some property which is missing in `SampleImportLogImpl`. This property is however present in the entity `Sample` which I am displaying in the `view_details.jsp`.

How to solve this? Do I need to create a separate portlet for the details coming from different entity?

Comment: How does your view_details.jsp look like? Specifically the searchcontainer tags

Comment: I have added the searchContainer codes for both pages `view.jsp` and `view_details.jsp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was displaying `SampleImportLog` entities in `view.jsp` search container. After clicking on a row, I was displaying `Sample` entities in `view_details.jsp` search container. In `view_details.jsp` when I was trying to sort the search container results, I was getting the error **Unknown property 'xxx' on class com.test.portlet.model.impl.SampleImportLogImpl'**.

I found out that I do not need to create a separate portlet for the details coming from different entity. The portlet is not tied to any entity and I can display whatever entities in the portlet jsp.

The error was the result of the failure to maintain the context of the search container in `view_details.jsp`. As such any action performed on search container was resulting the navigation away to the portlet default page  `view.jsp`. And the entity being displayed in the `view.jsp` search container did not have the property by which I was trying to sort the search container in `view_details.jsp`.

So to maintain the context of search container in `view_details.jsp`, I defined

```
<liferay-portlet:renderURL  varImpl="iteratorURL">
        <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/sample/sampleimportlog/view_details.jsp" />
        <portlet:param name="uuid" value="<%= uuid %>" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>
```

Then in the `searchContainer` in `view_details.jsp`,  I set the `iteratorURL`.

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="sample-empty-results-message"  orderByType="<%= orderByType %>" iteratorURL="<%=iteratorURL %>">
```

And it worked fine. Now I can sort the search container results based on different properties of `Sample` entity in `view_details.jsp`.